# Python Pandas Dataframe Columns of Lists, Get Intersection And Apply Function To Another Column

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, intersection

**Problem Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword': ['basement finishing systems akron pa', 'basement finishing systems biglerville pa', 'basement finishing systems chambersburg pa', 'basement finishing systems christiana pa', 'basement finishing systems delta pa'], 'StemmedKW': [['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'akron', 'pa'], ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'biglervil', 'pa'], ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'chambersburg', 'pa'], ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'christiana', 'pa'], ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'delta', 'pa']], 'Ad Group': ['Finishing System', 'Finishing System', 'Finishing System', 'Finishing System', 'Finishing System'], 'Campaign': ['Campaign A', 'Campaign A', 'Campaign A', 'Campaign A', 'Campaign A'], 'StemmedAG': [['finish', 'system'], ['finish', 'system'], ['finish', 'system'], ['finish', 'system'], ['finish', 'system']]}, columns=['Campaign', 'Ad Group', 'Keyword', 'StemmedAG', 'StemmedKW'])
```

**Dataframe Looks Like This**

```
     Campaign          Ad Group                                     Keyword  \
0  Campaign A  Finishing System         basement finishing systems akron pa   
1  Campaign A  Finishing System   basement finishing systems biglerville pa   
2  Campaign A  Finishing System  basement finishing systems chambersburg pa   
3  Campaign A  Finishing System    basement finishing systems christiana pa   
4  Campaign A  Finishing System         basement finishing systems delta pa   

          StemmedAG                                     StemmedKW  
0  [finish, system]         [basement, finish, system, akron, pa]  
1  [finish, system]     [basement, finish, system, biglervil, pa]  
2  [finish, system]  [basement, finish, system, chambersburg, pa]  
3  [finish, system]    [basement, finish, system, christiana, pa]  
4  [finish, system]         [basement, finish, system, delta, pa]
```

**Context**

`StemmedAG` and `StemmedKW` are columns of lists. I produced these columns by word stemming the `Ad Group` and `Keyword` columns. The goal is to put a plus sign `+` in front of the keywords in the `Keyword` column for any words that appear in both `StemmedAG` and `StemmedKW`.

**Result**

Note how `row 0` `Keyword` has the value `basement +finishing +systems akron pa`?  This would happen because the word `finish` and `system` both appear in `StemmedAG` and `StemmedKW`.  Therefore, plus signs are put in front of the non-stemmed words in the `Keyword` column.

```
     Campaign          Ad Group                                       Keyword  \
0  Campaign A  Finishing System         basement +finishing +systems akron pa   
1  Campaign A  Finishing System   basement +finishing +systems biglerville pa   
2  Campaign A  Finishing System  basement +finishing +systems chambersburg pa   
3  Campaign A  Finishing System    basement +finishing +systems christiana pa   
4  Campaign A  Finishing System         basement +finishing +systems delta pa   

              StemmedAG                                          StemmedKW  
0  ['finish', 'system']    ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'akron', 'pa']  
1  ['finish', 'system']  ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'biglervil', ...  
2  ['finish', 'system']  ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'chambersburg...  
3  ['finish', 'system']  ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'christiana',...  
4  ['finish', 'system']    ['basement', 'finish', 'system', 'delta', 'pa']
```

I'm not used to working with `lists` in columns of Pandas and don't know how to get the intersection of `lists` from two columns in a `dataframe`, then get the index of where the words appear, then apply plus signs to the front of each found index.  Or maybe easier would be a string replacement on `df['Keyword']` using the words from `StemmedAG`?

I'd also like to do this the most pandas way possible and avoid `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to achieve this with a non-pandas approach but it's pretty nasty. I was really hoping to learn how to do this with pandas (if it's even possible!)

```
for idx in df.index:
    intersect = list(set(df['StemmedAG'][idx]).intersection(df['StemmedKW'][idx]))
    positions = [i for word in intersect for i, j in enumerate(df['StemmedKW'][idx]) if j == word]
    df.loc[idx, 'Keyword'] = ' '.join(["+"+word if df['Keyword'][idx].split().index(word) in positions else word for word in df['Keyword'][idx].split()])
```